# Change the name of resources created by Kubernetes in Azure?

Tags: azure, kubernetes

When I create a new *Kubernetes service* in Azure a new *Resource group* is created which contains all resources associated with it (like Ip adreses, disks etc). Our ops team asked me to define the names of these resources dynamically so that when a new resource is created our naming convention is used instead of the Kubernetes original one (example below). I assume that in the best case this will only work for new clusters. Does anyone know how it can be done?
Note that it would also help me a lot if I know for sure that I can not be done (without an unreasonable amount of work).

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/faq#can-i-provide-my-own-name-for-the-aks-node-resource-group) it sas that *As you work with the node resource group, keep in mind that you can't: Specify names for the managed resources within the node resource group.* Does this mean that what I want to do is not possible or that it is not possible after the cluster has been created?

**Example of what I want to do**: Currently *Public IP addresses* are called *kubernetes-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx* (where x is a random string). Instead, I want them to be called something like *IP-kubernetes-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx*

Comment: You answered your own question with the link to the FAQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**

It is not possible, and I don't think it will ever be.
That resource group is managed by Microsoft. It is created under your subscription so that you have a clear view over costs, but making changes in those resource might result in loosing Microsoft support

**Long answer**

That resource group is know as `nodeResourceGroup`. In there you should not:

- Specify names for the managed resources within the node resource group.
- Modify or delete managed resources within the node resource group.

Modifying any resource under the node resource group in the AKS cluster **is an unsupported action**, which breaks the service-level objective (SLO).

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/faq#can-i-modify-tags-and-other-properties-of-the-aks-resources-in-the-node-resource-group

Comment: If I create an Azure Disks by Persistent Volumes in Kubernetes it is saved in the *nodeResourceGroup*.  If the retain policy is now set to true the Disk can not be deleted from Kubernetes.
Is this an exception from your long answer (as I have to delete managed resources) or is there another way how this should be done?
While this case should not happen often in a running system, in development it happens regularly.

Comment: Hey Manuel! If you are deleting your cluster, then deleting resources is ok, since you will not need support for that cluster anymore :)  - If you want to know if there is a better way for your particular case, feel free to write me at carlos.garcia[at]microsoft.com and I can follow up with you ;)

Answer (score 1):

I create ARM templates to manage Azure resources with nominated naming. But not did with Azure AKS.

So I am not sure if it is possibile, until you test it and feedback.

For example, when we created a public IP address, I can nominate its name within ARM template

```
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
      "apiVersion": "2020-07-01",
      "name": "[parameters('PublicIPName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
          "name": "Standard",
          "tier": "Regional"
      },
      "properties": {
        "publicIPAllocationMethod": "Static"
      }
    }
```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.network/publicipaddresses?tabs=json

Comment: This should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

As the article that you linked to says, you can specify the name of the managed resource group (only at cluster creation), but you cannot specify the names of the resources that get created inside that RG.